# stream_context_create not working with https

Tags: php, api, magento2

I am using custom code for magento2 api in rest api method. My site is secured with SSL. my restapi is working fine with http and **not with https**, here is my code..

```
<?php
$base_url="http://mysite/";
$url = $base_url.'index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$body = '{"username":"ApiUser", "password":"ApiPass"}';
$header = 'Content-type: application/json';
$options = [    'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $body,
                'header' => $header
           ];
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => $options]);
$token = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));

// Some settings

$header = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token . "\r\n"
    . 'Content-type: application/json';
$options = [    'method' => 'GET',
                'content' => $body,
                'header' => $header
           ];
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => $options]);

$sku="1234";
$url = $base_url.'index.php/rest/V1/products/'.$sku;
$json_contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context) . "\n";
$result = json_decode($json_contents);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

I use many https coding, but no one is working it returns 500 error and i search i got an piece of code to check the status

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_export($w);
```

it returns,

```
openssl: yes
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: yes
wrappers: array(11) {
  [...]
}
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.